# Can I still fight for one side or the other after forging the truce in "Season Unending"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim if I haven't done any of the missions to join the imperials or the stormcloaks or signed up for them, can I do so after completing the quest "Season Unending"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After completing the peace treaty, you will be unable to do any of the civil war quests until you've completed the main quest line.

Comment: Well, that's not so bad. Thanks! Good not-spoilerage too.

Comment: Hey I beat the main quest and I still cant do the civil war