# Is it possible to continue the Main Quest Line if I took Whiterun with the Stormcloaks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After taking Whiterun, Vignar becomes the Jarl of the city, will he help me like Balgruff did ? Will he help me to capture Odahviing ?! Thanks a lot !!

Phil

Comment: I'm positive you can otherwise the game would be broken. the quest to set up the Moot i think is skipped if you complete the civil war quest line and you need Whiterun to no longer be contested by either side in order to use Dragon's Reach (all assumptions, never did that part myself)

Answer (score 2):

Vignar will in fact help you capture Odahviing.

However, I advise doing the civil war quest AFTER the main quest line. This makes sure nothing is broken. It also gives you only one thing to worry about.

Skyrim is a complicated game, and a multitude of sequences can break others.

If Vignar doesn't want to help you, make sure you are a Thane in Whiterun.

If that doesn't work, use the console.

Comment: You can't actually. As part of the main story line the Civil War quest line has to be completed. If it is not then there is a part of the main quest line where you have to pick who wins right then and there.

Comment: I killed Alduin before dealing with the war. Where are you in the main quest?

Comment: I can confirm you can completely skip the war and everything related when doing the main quest. I'm not sure what triggered the event you are talking about (I think I had to make that choice as well in some playthrough), but it is avoidable.

Comment: I completed the civil war quest after killing Alduin, but part of the process was to bring Ulfric and Tullius to the Greybeards' place to discuss a truce.

Comment: Sorry for the late delay but if you have not done the civil war the Jarl of Whiterun should refuse to help you capture a dragon until things are decided. This is where the quest Seasons Unending (This is the truce talks mentioned by George T) is triggered. The only exception to this should be when the civil war has already started and you have captured 8 holds in which case a truce can not be negotiated and I believe it must just be finished. You can find very detailed info: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending and overall http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Civil_War

Comment: Take a peek at this answer here, I think this is where the confusion is for you guys: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/43223/8581 Once the main quest line is done you can indeed then do the civil war even though you negotiated the truce in Seasons Unending.