# Can I be with the StormCloaks, do "Season Unending" and AFTER the MQ line, finish the Civil War?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, if I pick my side (Stormcloaks here) will I be able to do the Peace Truce ? Cause I would love to do it, but as soon as I killed Alduin, I continue the Civil War quests line. I would not take whiterun before the Truce, I would just maybe go to Korvanjund and take the Jagged Crown..! So, will it be ok? Or will my game be like "what did you do" Thanks :)

Phil

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43223/can-i-still-fight-for-one-side-or-the-other-after-forging-the-truce-in-season-u?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You can and must do "Season Unending" regardless of whether you side with the Imperials or Stormcloaks and whether the Jarl is Balgruuf or Vignar has taken over. The only exception to this is if you fully complete the civil war questline (Either taking Solitude as the Stormcloaks or Windhelm as the Imperials) and end the war that way.

Once you've done this quest, the civil war is put on hold until the main quest is finished and Alduin is defeated. Once you've defeated Alduin, the civil war resumes and you can continue fighting for your chosen side.

You may end up skipping or repeating parts of the civil war quest, depending on what you negotiated.

Comment: Will I do "season unending" if I took whiterun with Ulfric and the Jarl changes as Vignar ?

Comment: @Phil Yes. I actually edited that into the answer when you posted earlier.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this :) It should be strange that Vignar wants a Peace Truce ? He is obssess by the idea off beating the Empire ! Funny

Comment: @Phil It's a temporary cease-fire to deal with Alduin. Not much point in a free and independent Skyrim if Alduin devours the entire world.